# Recommendation for Machine Learning Computer

Tags: graphics-cards

I want to build a computer for machine learning using this processor:
[AMD Ryzen™ Threadripper 3970X](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-threadripper-3970x#product-specs)

Which of these graphics cards is the best for AI?

- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080
- NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060
- NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080

I also need recommendations for the following components:

- A motherboard that works well with this processor and graphics card.
- RAM
  Which brands are good?
  How much memory will I need?
- Storage Device(s)
  Which brands are good?
  How much space will I need?
- Cooling
- PC Tower/Case

Comment: I think you should provide some additional information: What kind of AI? Will you be using something like [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) which actually *uses* a GPU for learning? (Some AI frameworks do not use a GPU! But that CPU would be great with those frameworks anyways...) Also, you should be telling *us* you how much space you will need, that depends on your AI training data and other programs you want to use.

Comment: And the budget or max price! Otherwise we'll be recommending [4 of these](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/deep-learning-ai/products/titan-rtx/)...

Comment: hello @romen, thanks for the graphic card recommendation. it should a good a.i. computer on average. there is no limit for price.